# how to use express router ? my router with express doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a probleme with a route "router.get('/:nom/', function(req, res, next) {" doesn't work
I'm on a remote server on local its works fine
Really I don't understand
I tried with router.get('/accueil (home)

My server.js

```js
var express = require('express')

var middelware = require('./routes/mw')
var http = require('http')
var path = require('path');
//var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");


//console.log(session);
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/css')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascript')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/image')));
app.use('/',middelware );
console.log(__dirname+"test");
app.listen(8080)
console.log('8080 is the magic port');
```

my milldelware mw.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var url = require('url');
var router = express.Router();
console.log(router);
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
console.log("out"); out is only display 


//ROUTE and CALLBACK doesn't run 
router.get('/:nom/', function(req, res, next) {// URL 
    
  var pages=['accueil','article','contact'];
  var bool=false;
  console.log(req.params.nom+" in");
  pages.forEach(function(nomPage) {
  
  if(nomPage==req.params.nom){
  bool=true;
  console.log(nomPage);
  nomP=req.params.nom;
  // requete mysql 
  var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port:3306,
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "pageweb"
  }); 
  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    
   // Select where 
    con.query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE nomP = '"+nomP+"'", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    ctnpage=result[0].contenuP;
    console.log(ctnpage);
    // affichage via ejs dans la page 
    res.render('index', {
        contenuP:ctnpage ,
        nomP:pages
    });
  });
 
});
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  
  
  
  //res.send(html);

  }
  /*if(bool==false){
  res.redirect('/nom/accueil/');
  console.log("Page is redirected");
  }
  });*/
  
  })
  if(!bool){
  console.log("Page is redirected");
  res.redirect('http://www.olopherne.online/accueil/');  
  res.end("something");
  }
  });

/*
router.get('/storeredis', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.session.userId);
  var html="<h1>Erreur 404, cette page n'existe pas !<br> URL "+req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl+" inconnue</h1>";
  
  res.send(html);
});
*/


module.exports = router;
```

I am never in my route
Maybe a problem of path? different from the local?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you calling your service from another domain?

Comment: No it's a same domain
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

it's resolved the probleme was to delete the www. in the url !